# How do I make it so that pressing Enter only sends me to the character selection when I am on the title screen?

Tags: python, python-turtle

When I start my game it first shows the title screen and when I press Enter it goes to the character selection screen. This is intended, however at anytime if I press Enter, whether after the title screen or not, it will go to character selection.

Is there a way I can make it so that the `onkeypress` only works when I am on the title screen?

I have tried to move the `onkeypress` into my function that opens the title screen and I have also tried to make an `if` statement that says "if it is on the title screen then my onkeypress", however neither solution worked.

How can I do this correctly? I am working in replit.

```
import turtle as trtl
wn = trtl.Screen()
wn.setup(1280,720)

#the turtles
why = trtl.Turtle()
why2 = trtl.Turtle()
why3 = trtl.Turtle()

wn.bgcolor("dim grey")

#characters
closed = "mouthclosed.gif"
opened = "mouthopen.gif"
thumb = "thumb.gif"
cclosed = "mouthclosedc.gif"
copened = "mouthopenc.gif"
thumbc = "thumbc.gif"
#backgrounds
bikini = "bikini.gif"


wn.addshape(closed)
wn.addshape(opened)
wn.addshape(cclosed)
wn.addshape(copened)
wn.addshape(thumb)
wn.addshape(thumbc)


def title():
  why.pu()
  why2.pu()
  why3.pu()
  why.goto(0,300)
  why.color("rebecca purple")
  why.write("mouth pop game !", align="center",font=("Courier", 40, "bold"))
  why.goto(0,250)
  why.color("royal blue")
  why.write("Press enter to start", align="center",font=("Courier", 40, "bold"))
title()



def character_select():
  why.clear()
  why.goto(0,300)
  why.color("royal blue")
  why.write("Choose your Character", align="center",font=("Courier", 40, "bold"))
  why.goto(-200,0)
  why.shape(thumb)
  why2.goto(200,0)
  why2.shape(thumbc)


def godspeed():
  why.shape(opened)
def ohdear():
  why.shape(closed)
def bikinimc():
  wn.bgpic(bikini)

wn.onkeypress(character_select,"Return")

wn.onkeypress(godspeed,"a")
wn.onkeypress(ohdear, "s")
wn.onkeypress(bikinimc,"c")
wn.listen()
wn.mainloop()
```

I tried to solve it by adding a variable called `a` that equals 1 at the beginning and it adds one to `a` at the end of `character_select`:

```
if a == 1:
  wn.onkeypress(character_select, "Return")
```

Comment: ```wn.onkeypress()``` looks to bind keypress to the main screen. Which object has the title screen and so can you do ```<titlescreen>.onkeypress()```?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The check whether `a` is equal to 1 needs to be done *every time* the Enter key is pressed.

Your attempt

> ```
> if a == 1:
>   wn.onkeypress(character_select, "Return")
> ```

was not effective, because this is only executed *once* during the program.

Instead, move the check *inside* the `character_select` function. Either as a *positive* check:

```
def character_select():
    global a
    if a == 1:
        # ... code for going to character selection screen ...
        a += 1
```

or as a *negative* check with an "early return":

```
def character_select():
    global a
    if a != 1:
        return  # do NOT go to character selection screen

    # ... code for going to character selection screen ...
    a += 1
```

Notice that the code for going to the character selection screen must not be indented to be inside the `if` statement in this case.

Also notice that in order to assign to the `a` variable from inside `character_select` you need to mark it as `global`.